# Moodle and SAML2 SSO Auth plugin loops

Tags: php, moodle, saml-2.0

Moodle 3.5.1
plugin auth_saml2sso_moodle35_2018051500.zip

Question:
I guess I have the same error as Naaman Fallouh at
 https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_saml2sso (comments page 2)

I am able to login with phpBB/SAML and have
http://moodle.localhost/
and
http://moodle.localhost/simplesaml
I am able to login using http://moodle.localhost/simplesaml
I am able to login using http://moodle.localhost/ but after the login I get stuck in a loop:

http://saml_idp.localhost/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php?SAMLRequest=chars&RelayState=http%3A%2F%2Fmoodle.localhost%2Flogin%2Findex.php
(saml_idp.localhost is indeed my idp)

Over and over again, with every time other value for chars.

I did set in http://moodle.localhost/simplesaml/config/config.php
'session.phpsession.cookiename' => 'MoodleSession',

That is the only difference from the
`phpbb3.localhost/simplesaml/config/config.php`.

What else could be wrong? What's your first thought I should look at?

I use the example userpass authentication and defined a user like so:

```
'admin:admin' => array(
    'urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1' => array('admin'),
    'idnumber'=> array('123'),
    'email' => array('email@admin.nl'),
    'firstname' => array('firstadmin'),
    'lastname' => array('lastadmin'),
    "phone1" => array('admin'),
    "phone2" => array('admin'),
    "department" => array('admin'),
    "address" => array('admin'),
    "city" => array('admin'),
    "country" => array('admin'),
    "description" => array('admin'),
    "idnumber" => array('admin'),
    "lang" => array('admin'),
    "guid" => array('admin'),
    'urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.1' => array('globaladministrators'),
),
```

In Moodle the plugin configuration I set
Username attribute to: `urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1`

Would that not be enough?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question has quite a few problems: firstly, you need to include your question as text in the body of the question, not in a link; secondly, there's no point posting links to your own machine with host name `localhost`. See https://stackoverflow.com/how-to-ask

Comment: yeah i am still unsure how to overcome urls beging displayed as links. Pardon me.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by using sql for session.